# Местоимение "Я" в дневниковых записях

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов, местоимения

В формате дневниковых записей нередко приходится описывать события от первого лица:
*Проснувшись, я почувствовала непривычную свежесть в воздухе. Я приподнялась на кровати и осмотрелась.* В данном предложении я столкнулась с проблемой "яканья". Попробовала заменить местоимение деепричастием, но у меня вновь ничего не вышло: *Проснувшись, я почувствовала непривычную свежесть в воздухе. Приподнявшись на кровати, я осмотрелась.*
Допустимо ли такое употребление местоимения? Очень прошу помочь с заменой.

Comment: Попутное замечание: сразу две ошибки в употреблении деепричастного оборота:  "Попробовав заменить местоимение деепричастием у меня вновь ничего не вышло"

Comment: Даже не заметила при написании вопроса. Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы не бросалось в глаза "я", можно его просто опускать, пусть будет неполное предложение или определённо-личное, если в настоящем времени:

*Проснувшись, я почувствовала непривычную свежесть в воздухе. Приподнялась на кровати и осмотрелась*.

Или: *Проснувшись, я почувствовала непривычную свежесть в воздухе. Приподнявшись на кровати, осмотрелась.*

Answer (score 1):

> Проснувшись, я почувствовала непривычную свежесть в воздухе. Я приподнялась на кровати и осмотрелась.

Не вижу ничего страшного в повторном Я. Но третье будет уже перебором.

Можно опустить второе Я, но важно не потерять ритм рассказа:

**Проснувшись, я почувствовала непривычную свежесть в воздухе. Приподнялась на кровати и осмотрелась: в угу комнаты стоял инопланетянин.**

Answer (score 0):

**Проснувшись, я почувствовала непривычную свежесть в воздухе. Приподнявшись на кровати, осмотрелась...**

Дальше текст можно продолжить, но употреблять местоимение "я" два раза подряд не стоит.